# Android: how to tell when the camera is activated

Tags: android, camera

I'm writing an Android app that the user can run in the background to detect when the camera is turned on(by the user, or by other apps). This should also detect even in the scenario where other apps (like facebook, instagram) do not use the default android camera app.

I've been searching but haven't seen any broadcasts that are sent whenever the camera is activated. So far, I've seen that there's Camera.open() that throws a RuntimeException if the camera is already in use by another app. So one way is to keep polling Camera.open(), but it's really expensive. Is there a better alternative?

Thanks

Edit: Sorry i didn't mention it clearly but what I want to do is to create some kind of camera usage log: what time it was turned on/off, how long was the duration, etc..

Comment: What makes you think that you have the right to know when other apps use the camera?

Comment: I'm new to Android and from what I've been reading, the camera is a shared resource, so I'm thinking it wouldn't be too unreasonable to want to know when it's turned on/off.

Comment: The user can tell if the camera is in use, because the user is using the camera.

Comment: oh, sorry i didn't mentioned it clearly but what I want to do is to create some kind of camera usage log: what time it was turned on/off, how long was the duration, etc...

Comment: Can't you know if your camera is in use or not? It's your device so you should know whatever you want shouldn't you?

Comment: No one thought of the case that the camera might be in use by a malware of some kind? And no, the user is not able to know if the camera is been used by a malware without his knowledge.. That's the point!

Answer (score 3):

What happens internally is Camera API talks to CameraService and CameraService has mBusy variable which tracks whether camera is busy or not. And there is no API to get this mBusy flag out of service (without calling open())

I may be wrong, because I just glanced over it.

You can download Android source code (http://source.android.com/) and take a closer look yourself.

Files which could be interesting for you are:

\frameworks\base\services\camera\libcameraservice\CameraService.cpp

\frameworks\base\libs\camera\Camera.cpp

\frameworks\base\core\java\android\hardware\Camera.java

\frameworks\base\core\jni\android_hardware_Camera.cpp

One other idea. Try to look in the logs. In the case, if logs aren't turned off for Camera services/API, you can parse the logs to check when the camera was turned on or off. However, it may not work in OS 4.1, because Google limited reading of system logs.